# Converting C# to VB.NET: why is static method not visible?

Tags: c#, vb.net, methods

I have a C# method in my datatier that I am trying to convert to VB.Net. I converted it to VB.Net but when I bring up the datatier class the method is not showing. It has been a long time since i have used VB.Net and forgot alot of things

Here is my c# method:

```
public static useraccount UserActInfo(string empnumber)
{
    SQLConnectivity db = new SQLConnectivity();
    SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[1];
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    useraccount user = new useraccount();

    param[0] = db.MakeInputParameter("@UserEmpNumber", empnumber);
    db.RunExecuteProcedure("dc_SELECT_UserActInfo_By_EmpNumber", param, ref dt);

    if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        user.ID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["UserID"].ToString());
        user.FirstName = dt.Rows[0]["FName"].ToString();
        user.LastName = dt.Rows[0]["LName"].ToString();
        user.MiddleName = dt.Rows[0]["MName"].ToString();
        user.Title = dt.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();
        user.PhoneNo1 = dt.Rows[0]["PhoneNumber1"].ToString();
        user.PhoneNo2 = dt.Rows[0]["PhoneNumber2"].ToString();
        user.Fax = dt.Rows[0]["FaxNumber"].ToString();
        user.Email = dt.Rows[0]["Email"].ToString();
        user.StreetAddress = dt.Rows[0]["StreetAddress"].ToString();
        user.Locality = dt.Rows[0]["Locality"].ToString();
        user.Province = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Province"].ToString());
        user.PostalCode = dt.Rows[0]["PostalCode"].ToString();
        user.EmpNumberID = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["EmployeeNumberID"].ToString());
        user.EmpNumber = dt.Rows[0]["EmployeeNumber"].ToString();
    }
    if (user.ID != 0) { return user; }
    else { return null; }
}
```

I believe it has to do with the declaration, which i have as:

```
Public Static Function UserActInfo(ByVal _eno As String) As useraccount
```

Why can I not see the method

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Static in C# is Shared in VB.Net.

So if you convert your code above it will be:

```vb
 Public Shared Function UserActInfo(ByVal empNumber As String) As UserAccount
     'code here
 End Function
```

You could use this [online converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) by Telerik to help you with the conversions.

Comment: @MSI You could also use developerfusion's online converter that can help you convert code from C#/VB.NET to C#/VB.NET/Ruby/Python. http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/